# How can I run a Node.js app using grunt-contrib-watch?

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, grunt-contrib-watch

For example, I have a project folder "myProject" with the following files:

```
/myProject/app.js
/myProject/foo.json
```

Is there a way to setup grunt-contrib-watch to run app.js any time foo.json is modified?

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
shell: {
    runapptask: {
        command: [
             'node /myPorject/app.js'
        ]
    }
},
watch: {
    runapp: {
        files: ['/myproject/foo.json'],
        tasks: ['shell:runapptask']
    }
}
```